# Python: RegEx assistance

Tags: python, regex

I have a filename `10.10.10.17_super-micro-100-13.txt` from which I need to extract everything between `_` and `.`. E.g., in this case it would return `super-micro-100-13`

I will need a Python regex to accomplish the task. If I do 
`re.compile('\_(.*)\.)`, I get `_super-micro-100-13.` which is not what I want. Can anyone throw some light on what would be the correct regex in this case?

Thanks,
Neel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookbehind and lookahead so that you are only actually matching the part that you want.  Also note that you need to escape the `.` at the end to match a literal dot.

Here is the regex you could use:

```
regex = re.compile(r'(?<=_).*(?=\.)')
```

Alternatively, you can use your current regex and pull out the first capture group from your match:

```
regex = re.compile(r'_(.*)\.')
print regex.search('10.10.10.17_super-micro-100-13.txt').group(1)
# super-micro-100-13
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decide you don't need to use regex, throwing together a few string methods is more readable.

```
file_name = "10.10.10.17_super-micro-100-13.txt"
print file_name.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import re
name = '10.10.10.17_super-micro-100-13.txt'
regex = re.compile(r'.+_(.+)\.txt')
regex.match(name).group(1)
> 'super-micro-100-13'
```

Answer (score 1):

I do think that regex is a bit overkill. You can use the "**find**" function as follow:

```
def extract_info(s):
    underscore = s.find('_')
    dot = s.find('_', underscore) //you only want a dot after the underscore
    return s[underscore:dot]
```